# Can I import bcrypted passwords into Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a database of users with bcrypted passwords. Obviously, I cannot turn them into plaintext passwords, but that is what seems to be expected in the AD Graph API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/passwordprofile?view=graph-rest-1.0

Since my database is not an Active Directory, the AD Connect also will not work.
Is there any way to migrate the passwords to AD without bothering users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, instead use this approach:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-migration#seamless-migration

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration/tree/master/seamless-account-migration

Comment: Thanks, I did not find those pages earlier!